# Timing out UDP socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets

I am a python newbie, digging into an old code written for Python 1.5 . It basically implements a UDP server for reading in the data sent from a client. The code looks like as follows:

```
import socket
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
serverSocket.bind('localhost', 778)
msg, sndr = serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)
```

The problem with this socket is that it can wait infinitely for the message to receive (a source of bug which I am trying to fix), in case of a client send failure. I know that from Python 2.3 onwards, a `settimeout` method is available, but unfortunately I have to be stuck with Python 1.5 . It would be great if somebody can help me with a code snippet/idea to have my own timeout feature here.

Comment: deathly curious: why on earth are you stuck with python 1.5??  that is _beyond_ ancient.

Comment: Eevee, I am looking into a code developed probably a decade back. I am not the original developer, hence I am just trying to fix a bug recently reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have found a workaround to this problem by using `select` module.

Code now looks as follows:

```
import socket, select
serverSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
serverSocket.bind('localhost',778)
while running:    #running variable is set to True
    incoming = select.select([serverSocket],[],[],5) #5 corresponds to timeout in seconds
    try:
        msg,sndr = incoming[0][0].recvfrom(2048)
    except IndexError:
        sys.stderr.write('Timed out in receiving message on UDP server')
        continue
```

Answer (score 3):

Any [socket tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html) in any language would explain the select call to set timeouts on sockets.  There is no reason to look at papyrus-based python.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont find any other solution you can try using this timeout decorator which I wrote some time ago. Check if it works

```
import ctypes
import threading
import time

class timeout:
    def __init__(self, timeout, kill_on_timeout=True):
        self.__timeout = timeout
        self.__kill_on_timeout = kill_on_timeout

    def __call__(self, func):
        def prep_func(*args, **kwargs):
            result = args[0]
            args = tuple(list(args)[1:])
            try:
                result.append(func(*args, **kwargs))
            except Exception as e:
                result.append(e)

        def timeout_func(*args, **kwargs):
            result = []
            args = tuple([result]+list(args))
            t = threading.Thread(target=prep_func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
            timeout_time = self.__timeout+time.time()
            while True:
                if time.time()>=timeout_time:
                    if self.__kill_on_timeout:
                        try:
                            terminate_thread(t)
                        except:
                            raise TimeoutReached('Could not kill the thread!')
                    raise TimeoutReached('Timeout reached! Thread killed.')
                if result:
                    if not issubclass(type(result[0]), BaseException):
                        return result[0] 
                    raise result[0]
                time.sleep(0.001)
        return timeout_func


def terminate_thread(thread):
    if not thread.isAlive():
        return None
    exc = ctypes.py_object(SystemExit)
    res = ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(
        ctypes.c_long(thread.ident), exc)
    if res == 0:
        raise ValueError('err')
    elif res > 1:
        ctypes.pythonapi.PyThreadState_SetAsyncExc(thread.ident, None)
        raise SystemError('err')

class TimeoutReached(Exception):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. But unfortunately, it cannot work in Python 1.5 as decorators came only after 2.4 :(
On trying this code, I get a large number of syntax errors, mostly to do with function objects.